# Using mcrypt_encrypt() give me warning "Size of key is too long"

Tags: php, 3des

I'm trying to use mcrypt_encrypt() in PHP but I've a problem when I use the function to encrypt:

My code is:

Vars:

```
$key = "1e1r1r1t1y1y1g1g1g1g1g1345678910"; // That is a example, the real key have 32 long too.
$ref="12013515"; // example value

// Tamanio Encripyt ....
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_3DES,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size,MCRYPT_RAND);
// Lunch
$stringEncrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES,$key,$ref,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);
```

If I do that, PHP show me the error:

```
Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): Size of key is too large for this algorithm
```

I need to use the encrypt 3DES...what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key of size 32 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of size 24 supported.

Answer (score 0):

Your key is to long. Maximum key length for 3DES in CBC mode is 24 chars.

3DES has a key length of 168 bit. 168 bit / 24 chars = 7 bit per char.

To get the max key length for a given algorith use:

```
mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_3DES,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)
```

@see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-key-size.php

Comment: I supposed that @maxhb but...The key have that size and I can't change the key and the mcrypt mode (3DES) How can set a bigger size?

Comment: @marcos That's not possible, 168bit is a technical limit. Maybe you can use some kind of key generating function to generate a 168bit key out of your input. Like md5(key) but with max 24 chars of output.

Comment: thanks for your help! I think so too, I don't know why give me that key with that size...I saw some codes to "fix" that. I think that is a wrong use or bad use because use a null value for the $iv.

Comment: I made some test and with that solution (ignore the size for the $iv) I can made the encription without problems. @maxhb

Answer (score 0):

For that case, I need to ignore the size value for this type of encription (I can't change the key and type of encription).

I read some post with the same problem and that solution.

Thanks everybody for the help.